# Saving Kafka headers as mongo fields with mongo sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm creating a generic service in .NET 6 using C# that will send events to Azure EventHubs that will in turn be consumed by a mongo sink connector. Everything works. Now I wanted the generic sevice to send some event headers to Azure EventHubs (Kafka) that will be read from the connector if I need. To do this I've used the only function I found com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.transform.common.HeaderToField$Value, but following the documentation I've got this:

```
{
  "transforms" : "headerToField",
  "transforms.headerToField.type" : "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.transform.common.HeaderToField$Value",
  "transforms.headerToField.header.mappings" : "applicationId:STRING"
}
```

But I get the following error: "MAP is not supported type", even though I'm sending as a string. Looking at the source code (https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-common/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/jcustenborder/kafka/connect/transform/common/BaseTransformation.java) it blows at line 120, because it thinks it's Map type. I think the issue with this is because the header it not being correctly sent, because Azure EventHubs sends with Amqp protocol that adds a few bytes in the string...
[image: amqp-headers]

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> even though I'm sending as a string

The error is referring to the value payload, not your header

Fields can only be added into structured events, such as from Protobuf/Avro serialized records, and not String/JSON data. For string data, though, you can use HoistField transform before HeaderToField

Comment: What's the idea then? Have something like this:
`
    transforms                          : "hoistField, headerToField"
    transforms.hoistField.type       : "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField$Value"
    transforms.hoistField.field       : "sentAt"
    transforms.headerToField.type       : "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.transform.common.HeaderToField$Value"
    transforms.headerToField.header.mappings : "sentAt:STRING"
`

How do I know the name of the header payload or value payload i need to hoistfield? The header name is called "sentAt"

Comment: The hoist field name is arbitrary. It wraps the whole value payload into a Struct (so, just name it `value`). Then the header would be inserted into that Struct. The field names should not match

Comment: Also, this assumes you're using StringConverter only, and not JSONConverter, or another

Comment: Yes I'm not using JSONConverter,  it's enabled: false. How do I make the HeaderToField$Value to read from this "value" struct and not from the original data? I just changed the field name of hoistField to "value" and I still get the same error

Comment: Not sure what you mean "enabled: false" ? The property `schemas.enabled` is only for JSONConverter, which would indicate you are using it. This [forces the value to a "Map type" when schemas are not enabled](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/), thus causing the error you are seeing. As mentioned, the HoistField is when using `value.converter: StringConverter`... But the down-side of that is that JSON may not be parsed, so you would may end up with something like `{"value": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"}`

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked even though I still get the amqp stuff, on the field, it looks like this: "�17/07/2023 10:39:28". Do you know a way to remove the first 2 chars of a string?
What about flatten and removal of the "value." of every key, is this possible?

Comment: That `�` character is some binary encoding, rather than "amqp stuff". You'd need to handle that some other way. I'm not sure what you mean by flattening; I don't have any experience with the Mongo connector